# Conditional formatting in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel, I am trying to format table cells as red if the current date - row date =3 months
this is how I did it: in controller

```
   public function get_rxs()
{
$ldate = Time();
$rxs = rxs::all();

return view('viewlog', [
    'rxs' => $rxs,
    'ldate' => $ldate
]);
```

in view:

```
 @foreach($rxs as $rx)
      <tr @if($ldate-$rx->rxdate>="7776000") class="table-danger" @else  @endif >
        <td>{{ $rx->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $rx->pt_name }} <br></td>
        <td>{{ $rx->dr_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ date("Y-m-d",$rx->rxdate) }}</td>
```

and i got the time saved as integer (epoch) the thing is it is calculating sec:min:hr and i really do not want to include that in the calculation since it may make it a split second difference between red formatting and regular and i want it to always use 00:00:00 time and whatever date it is.. how to do that.. I tried doing it with date() but it says invalid numerical data since i think date returns chars with numbers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used carbon dependencies and it worked like a charm
 Like this:
 1. added use Carbon\Carbon; in the controller
 2. Channged $ldate to this $ldate = Carbon::now()
 3. in the view I added this after foreach

```
<tr class="@if($ldate->diffindays($rx->rxdate)>="90") table-danger @elseif($ldate->diffindays($rx->rxdate)>="60") table-warning @endif" >>
```

and it started showing difference in days only

So I stopped using epoch format and used DateTime format instead

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<tr @if($ldate-$rx->rxdate>="7776000") class="table-danger" @else  @endif >`

to

`<tr class="{{ ($ldate->$rx->rxdate >= "7776000") ? 'table-danger' : ''}}">`

Comment: Actually that did not work , but i used carbon dependencies and it worked exactly as i wanted I will add it in the answer